# Transformar em link

Tags: php

Como faço para vereficar se o link já está correto(ex: https://stackoverflow.com). Minha aplicação pega o texto de uma base de dados, e lá pode estar escrita deste jeito: "stackoverflow.com".

Como fazer para que o código saiba se já tem, e se nao tiver adicionar ao texto?

Estou exibindo o link deste jeito, e nunca encaminha certo se não estiver com o "https://"

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)
echo "<a href=' " . $row['link'] .  " '><span style='padding: 3%'>" . $row['link'] . "</span>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar `preg_match()` para verificar se não contém a string na variável e concatenar:

```
if (!preg_match('/https/', $row['link'])) $row['link'] = "https://".$row['link'];
```

Ficaria assim:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)
if (!preg_match('/https/', $row['link'])) $row['link'] = "https://".$row['link'];
echo "<a href=' " . $row['link'] .  " '><span style='padding: 3%'>" . $row['link'] . "</span>";
```